# Grub messed up after switching SATA ports - ubuntu boot loop

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

So I moved my hardware into a new computer case and obviously switched the ports of my SSDs, which obviously screwed up my GRUB installation. First I ended up with a single blinking cursor, not loading GRUB at all, nor Kubuntu/Windows. Changing boot order in BIOS/EFI I could boot Windows, but not Kubuntu. Then I run into boot-repair and tryed that without real success.

I tried using `boot-repair-disk` running both SSD plugged in without successfully booting Kubuntu after. Then I unplugged the Windows SSD and run boot-repair again, without success again.

After boot-repair at least I am shown a GRUB menu with entries like

- Ubuntu
- Advanced Boot options
- /EFI/someFileX64.efi
- /EFI/someOtherFileX64.efi
- /EFI/someOtherFileX64.efi
- Windows Boot Loader <---- only working option so far

When I enter on "Ubuntu" the Kubuntu boot logo is shown and looped forever - never entering login screen. The other options throw some error and return to GRUB.

My system is set as follows as far as I can tell from Windows right now:

EFI System
2 SSDs - Dual boot Kubuntu 18 + Windows 10 (seperate SSDs)

SSD1 (Samsung) with

- sdX1 EFI
- sdX2 /
- sdX3 /home

SSD2 (Crucial) with

- sdX1 450MB Recovery partition (i guess)
- sdX2 100MB EFI-Systempartition
- sdX3 Windows (C:)
- sdX4 Epps (E:)
- sdX5 Games (G:)

So I can boot into Windows 10 without struggle but if I manage to choose Ubuntu in GRUB it loops on the Boot logo.

In my `fstab` I was mounting BYUUID the Epps partition because of a shared config folder. But regardless if the Windows SSD is plugged in or not, the boot logo loop happens.

Any ideas what I can do now?!

Comment: Please don't add something like "SOLVED" into the subject, that's not how StackExchange sites work. Mark your answer as accepted instead. See also https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Ok thank you for the information. I will remember that for the upcoming questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I plugged in my HDD, as well, I was able to boot Kubuntu again. I now remember, that I configured /etc/fstab also to mount my data partition (by UUID) from my HDD...

I guess I could have saved me a lot of trouble, if I had plugged in my HDD from the beginning. :D